# Can't find IPython Kernel .JSON file

Tags: raspberry-pi, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to setup a remote kernel on my Raspberry Pi right now, using IPython as my remote kernel and try to connect to this kernel using Spyder.
Using Spyder to create local kernels and use them to interpret code is working perfectly fine. Starting a kernel on my Raspberry Pi also works well using `ipython kernel`.

As described by many other users before, the .JSON file for the connection details I have to hand to Spyder, is located at `/home/<username>/.ipython/profile_default/security/kernel-<id>.json`. Unfortunately I can't find this .JSON file on my Raspberry Pi, but if I try to connect an existing kernel on my local PC I can find all local kernels.

What is the problem with the kernels on my Raspberry Pi? Why aren't they saved as .JSON files?

Another question: I accidently created another profile in IPython, how can I remove this profile?

Comment: What version of IPython do you have? The files may have changed name/location between versions. To delete a profile, just remove the `.ipython/profile_(whatever)` folder.

Answer (score 0):

On my Raspberry PI the .json are located in `/home/<username>/.config/ipython/profile_default/security/`